# node cannot read property of undefined

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express

I'm making api for foodtruck for practice I added

```
geometry: {
    type: { default: 'Point' },
    coordinates: [ Number ]
  }
```

geometry in the foodtruck model and I added

```
  api.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    let newFoodTruck = new FoodTruck()
    newFoodTruck.name = req.body.name
    newFoodTruck.foodtype = req.body.foodtype
    newFoodTruck.avgcost = req.body.avgcost
    newFoodTruck.geometry.coordinates = req.body.geometry.coordinates

    newFoodTruck.save(err => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      }
      res.json({ message: req.body.name+' FoodTruck saved successfully' })
    })
  })
```

geometry in the post to get the coordinates data from users when they request
but, when I tried to add the data like  (POST)http://localhost:3005/v1/foodtruck/add

```
{
    "name": "Hot dog",
    "foodtype": "Meet",
    "evgcost": 5.99,
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [35, 34]
    }
}
```

it returns

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;coordinates&#39; of undefined
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:/Users/Happy/Desktop/FoodTruckAPI/src/controller/foodtruck.js:15:59
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.handle (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Immediate.next (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\FoodTruckAPI\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm still confusing why it returns coordinates of undefined

Comment: are you including some modules that will parse body for you? example https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser ? Also try to console.log(req.body). Im pretty sure it's empty object or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the type

```
  geometry: {
    type: { type: String, default: 'Point' },
    coordinates: [ Number ]
  },
```

I missed type: String in geometry
but, I don't know why needed type for geometry because I only needed coordinates Number